# gcc compilation and assemblying

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, x86

I am trying to create an executable with gcc. I have two files virtualstack.c (which consists of the C-code below) and stack.s which consists of the intel x86 assembly code written in AT&T syntax (seen below the C-code). My command line command is `gcc -c virtualstack.c -s stack.s`, but I get two errors (line 3 in stack.s) - `missing symbol name in directive` and `no such instruction _stack_create`. I thought I have correctly declared functions from C in assembly prefixed with a underscore (`_`). I would be very grateful for any comments.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void stack_create(void);

int main(void)
{
stack_create();

return 0;
}
```

Assembly code:

```
.global _stack_create
    .type, @function

_stack_create
pushl   %ebp
movl    $5, %esp
movl    %esp, ebp
movl    $21, %edx
pushl   %edx
```

Comment: You need a colon after the second `_stack_create`. And I don't know if the line with `.type` is right, but it's not needed. Btw, moving 5 into `esp` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @alexey frunze. thank you:) now I feel stupid about the colon. I should have seen that one. Without the .type it compiles. I still need to see if it is executable. Thanks also for the esp warning.

Comment: well. I have removed the .type, @function. I discover that gcc creates separate objectfiles. I tried to write gcc -o vs virtualstack.c -s stack.s instead. I believed that should create an vs.out file (executable). Then I get undefined reference to stack_create in main() - got any ideas why?

Comment: What `-s` is for? Should work without it.

Comment: @alexey. Yes, I discovered that it worked without any flags. My code as is written creates a segmentation fault since i dont remove all the items from the stack..

Comment: Your assembly code is plain wrong. It trashes the stack pointer (by writing 5 into it) and if `pushl %edx` doesn't lead to an exception itself (because normally, the memory around address 0 is not accessible) then it causes the CPU to execute whatever garbage follows `pushl %edx` in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain you method how to investigate such cases.

1) It is always good idea to make compiler work for you. So lets start with code (lets call it assemble.c):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    /* stub stuff */
    void __attribute__ ((noinline))
    stack_create(void) { }

    int
    main(void)
    {
      stack_create();
      return 0;
    }
```

Now compile it to assembler with `gcc -S -g0 assemble.c`. stack_create function was assembled to (your results may differ, so please follow my instructions by yourself):

```
  .text
  .globl  stack_create
  .type stack_create, @function
stack_create:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  popq  %rbp
  ret
  .size stack_create, .-stack_create
```

2) Now all you need is to take this template and fill it with your stuff:

```
  .text
  .globl  stack_create
  .type stack_create, @function
stack_create:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp

  ;; Go and put your favorite stuff here!
  pushl   %ebp
  movl    $5, %esp
  movl    %esp, ebp
  movl    $21, %edx
  pushl   %edx
  ... etc ...

  popq  %rbp
  ret
  .size stack_create, .-stack_create
```

And of course make it separate `.s` file, say stack.s.

3) Now lets compile alltogether. Remove stub stuff from assemble.c and compile everything as:

```
gcc assemble.c stack.s
```

I got no errors. I believe you will get no errors too.

The main lesson: don't ever try to write in assembler in details like sections, function labels, etc. Compiler better knows how to do it. Use his knowledge instead.